# Почему в предложении правильно  употреблять "что" а не "то что"?

Tags: недопустимая-метка, фразеология

Кто может грамотно и внятно объяснить, почему в предложении правильно 
употреблять "что" а не "то что"?

К примеру:
Я вижу, что ты много знаешь. 
Я вижу, то что ты много знаешь.

Он договорился с ней, что купит продукты сам. 
Он договорился с ней, то что купит продукты сам.

Ольга выглянула в окно и увидела, что на улице идёт дождь.
Ольга выглянула в окно и увидела, то что на улице идёт дождь.

Лично мне режет слух повсеместное и неуместное употребление молодыми людьми в возрасте от 14 до 25 лет в предложениях  "то что" вместо грамотного "что". И это при том, что, и в школе и в старших учебных заведениях всегда и везде (Конечно, за исключением тех случаев, когда это действительно было необходимо!) писали именно "что" а не "то что". Я уже не говорю про художественную литературу.
Уже, наверное, лет 7-5  как я слышу везде, к месту и не к месту употребление в предложениях вместо обычного "что" это самое "то что". 
Очень хочу, чтобы мои дети были достаточно грамотными. Поэтому ищу  ответ на вопрос, как грамотно объяснить им этот момент.

Comment: А что вы хотите объяснить? Так не говорят, вот и все. Думаю, что это "точто" скоро уйдёт.

Comment: они сейчас говорят еще и вот так: "я столкнулась **с тем, то что** некоторые..."

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы грамотно писать и говорить, надо знать  вид предложений и понимать их структуру. Все приведенные примеры – это сложноподчиненные с придаточными изъяснительными, которые имеют следующие характерные особенности:

А.  СПП С ПРИДАТОЧНЫМИ ИЗЪЯСНИТЕЛЬНЫМИ

а) Придаточные изъяснительные предложения передают содержание мысли, чувства, речи и образуют так называемую косвенную речь.

б) Придаточные изъяснительные относятся опорному слову в предложении – глаголу, существительному или наречию.

в) Используемые союзы имеют следующие характеристики:  союз ЧТО – нейтральный;  союз КАК – достоверный;  союз БУДТО – вероятностный; союз ЧТОБЫ – желательный;  частица ЛИ – для передачи вопросительной речи. Например: Я сказал, что заблудился. Жаль, что он не приехал. Слышно, как дождь стучит по стеклу.   Говорили, будто его видели в городе. Я хочу, чтобы мы никогда не расставались. Я не знаю, вернемся ли мы сегодня домой.

г) союзные слова используются как исключение и являются вопросительными наречиями придаточного предложения, которые одновременно служат для связи двух предложений (союз в этом случае как бы пропускается): Я не знаю, когда вернусь. Даша забыла, зачем пришла.

Б. УКАЗАТЕЛЬНЫЕ СЛОВА

Указательные слова в СПП с придаточными изъяснительными  возможны, но они употребляются не всегда, а только при необходимости или желании ОБОЗНАЧИТЬ ТО ОПОРНОЕ СЛОВО, к которому относится придаточное. Указательные слова чаще относятся к опорным существительным и наречиям, например:  Мысль о том, что они расстанутся, стесняла её сердце. Его деятельность состояла в том, чтобы поглядывать на улицу.

Сравним: (1) «Он сказал, что надо соблюдать осторожность. (2) Он говорил (о том), что надо соблюдать осторожность. (3) Неправильно: Он сказал то, что надо  соблюдать осторожность». В первом случае указательное слово нежелательно, во втором случае возможно, а в третьем его использование является ошибкой:

В.  КОГДА МОЖНО ОШИБИТЬСЯ

Почему вариант (3)  для изъяснительных предложений не допускается? Дело в том, что  такую структуру имеют предложения другого вида, а именно МЕСТОИМЕННО-ОПРЕДЕЛИТЕЛЬНЫЕ предложения, в которых указательное слово ТО является ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНЫМ ЭЛЕМЕНТОМ:  «Я понял то, что давно уже было всем понятно».

Эти предложения построены следующим образом: указательное местоимение в главном предложении соотносится с СОЮЗНЫМ СЛОВОМ в придаточном предложении, при этом союзное слово ЧТО, в отличие от союза ЧТО, является ЧЛЕНОМ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ.

Иногда эти предложения очень похожи, например: «Я понял, что всем всё  известно (изъясн.) Неправильно: Я понял то, что всем всё известно (изъясн.). Я наконец понял то, что все уже давно знали (м.-опр.).

Answer (score 0):

1.1. **Если в "то(,) что" "то" - союз, а "что" и его падежные подобия - местоимение, то это грамотно и не отделяются запятой:**

> Когда я решал уравнение, то чем и о чём я думал?
>
> Ежели ты покупал в магазине, то что ты там держишь?

---

1.2.1. **Если же "то" и его падежные аналоги - это местоимение, а "что" - местоимение в роли союза (союзное слово-местоимение; в этом случае оно может склоняться) или же это сам союз (в этом случае не может сколняться), то отделяются запятой и это грамотно:**

> Он договорился с ней о том, что [союз] купит продукты сам.
>
> Он сказал ей о том, что/чего [союзное местоимение] именно будет куплено им.
>
> Он пояснил ей то, в чём [тоже союзное слово] будет принимать продукты.

*Вообще, можно не знать то, чем является слово "что", а только то, чем является слово "то": местоимением или союзом, - чтобы понять отличие.*

1.2.2. Вероятно, Ваша тема о "то, что" именно с запятой, то есть "то" - местоимение.

---

1.3. Бывают даже слияния:

> Если ты мне хотел сообщить кое о чём, то [союз] то [местоимение], что ты получил то, о чём ты мечтал, - выигрыш в миллиард рублей и славу в десять миллионов человек, - мне уже известно. Я за тебя очень рада!

---

2.1. Вообще-то, при "то", являющемся местоимением, "то, что" на самом деле можно употреблять вместо "что", притом это одно и то же. Но есть действительно частные случаи, когда оно само неграмотно либо каверкают на неграмотное: это пунктуация и неверный выбор падежа.

2.2. Итак, первая лажа (неграмотность) в употреблении "то, что" - это то, что опускают в ней запятую, а другую ненужную запятую пишут перед "то", а произношение соответственное: перед "то" ставят какую-то ненадобную паузу, а между "то" и "что" не ставят задержку; в общем, путают с "(), то что":

> Спасибо, за то что Вы мне помогли. Вы полностью доказали всем своё мастерство!
>
> Поэтому, то что касается тру-блюза…

2.3. Вторая - то, что иногда неверно падежи ставят в местоимении "то" в "то, что" - преимущественно в именительном падеже.

### ----------

---

2.4. Преимущественно неверно полагают то, что "то, что" - это якобы союз, поэтому типа его не существует и типа не грамотно его писать вместо "что" (и вообще, то, что его надо без запятой писать или даже слитно). Но это не союз. Это местоимение+союз/-ное местоимение. Если мыслить словосочетанием "то, что" правильно: как местоимением+союз/-ным местоимением, а не как типа союзом, - то будет проще понять, что это грамотное употребление. Ещё проще будет это осознать тогда, когда приведёте однокоренные подобия:

> тот, кто
>
> тогда, когда
>
> то, как (тут тоже не надо путать с "(), то как", также как "(), то что")
>
> так, как (не путать с союзом "так как", имеющим кардинально не то значение)
>
> то, чтобы

… и т. п. . Надеюсь, я Вам открыл глаза. То есть "то, что" вместо "что" можно писать ВСЕГДА, НО УЧИТЫВАЯ ПАДЕЖ!